# Change vibration sound like in Samsung Clock app

Tags: java, android, vibration, android-vibration

I wonder if it is possible to change the tone (not amplitude) of the vibration like it is done on Samsung Clock app. You can hear it in here:

https://youtu.be/3yyOSH5RP5g?t=134

The sound of the vibration on "off-beat" is different from all the ones before it. How is this accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: Repost of https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65420290/1